# Infinite loop. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i wanna test if my variable is empty or not to display some differents things.
When i don't use the else...if everything work but when i use this code :

```
<?php 
$Amazon = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Lien Amazon", true);
?>
<?php   
    if( $Amazon != NULL ){ 
        echo '<li><span class="post-meta-key"><a href=". $Amazon . ">Acheter sur Amazon</a></li>' ;} 
    else {
        echo '<li><span class="post-meta-key"><a href="https://www.amazon.fr/bd/b?ie=UTF8&node=301133">Acheter sur Amazon</a></li>' ;}  
        ?>
```

What is the problem ? Thank you

Comment: What has the title to do with the question? What is the problem?

Comment: `when i use this code` then WHAT?

Comment: Your amazon link can't work as you miss two single quotes around your concat. But this code can never generate an infinite loop - there is not even a regular one

Comment: Sorry , when i used this code my page charged infinitely and nothing happen.Where are the missing two singles quotes ?

Comment: "What is the problem ? Thank you" - The problem is simple. You provide poor information. [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm sorry i'm french so excuse my english.When i use the else...if nothing happen and my page stay blank.When i use the same code without the else...if everything work perfectly.

Comment: "but my page stays blank" --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an output error. You haven't closed and reopened the string on trying to concat a variable.

```
echo '<li><span class="post-meta-key"><a href=". $Amazon . ">Acheter sur Amazon</a></li>' ;
```

Do instead:

```
echo '<li><span class="post-meta-key"><a href="'. $Amazon . '">Acheter sur Amazon</a></li>' ;
```